# Function of an array with argument

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

Suppose c[i,t] is an array such as c[1,2]={1,2,3}

I want to define a function TOT[c[i,t]] which, for instance, computes Total[Array]. This does not work:

TOT[c[i_,t_]]:=Total[c[i,t]]

Any help?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is `c[i_, t_]` a function that returns a one-dimensional list? If so, then `c[1, 2] // Total` should give you what you want.

Comment: Writing the definition as `TOT[c[i_, t_]] := Total[c[i, t]]` is problematic because your expression likely does not retain the `Head` `c` when passed to `TOT.` Try something like `TOT = c /* Total`. Then `TOT[1, 2] = Total[c[1, 2]]`, which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`HoldFirst`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) attribute on your `TOT` function:

```
c[1, 2] = {1, 2, 3};

SetAttributes[TOT, HoldFirst];
TOT[c[i_, t_]] := Total[c[i, t]]

TOT[c[1, 2]]
(*    6    *)
```

Comment: This is is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Comment: It is generally a good practice  to set `Attributes` before any definitions because attributes also affect how patterns on the _lhs_ are treated.

Comment: Thanks @Anton.Sakovich for the hint, I've updated the submission.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply:

````
c[1, 2] = {1, 2, 3};

TOT[lst_] := Total[lst]

TOT[c[1, 2]]
(* 6 *)
```
````

Comment: or even `TOT=Total`